# Time difference between callings of a method

Tags: c#, time, mono, timing

One part of my program calls a certain method several times.

How can this method track the time between each time it is called?

I thought to use some global variables:

```
var lastTime = ?;
var currentTime = ?;
var elapsedTime = ?;

public DoSomething()
{
    currentTime = TimeRightNowInSeconds;
    elapsedTime = currentTime - lastTime;
    // do stuff with elapsedTime...
    lastTime = TimeRightNowInSeconds;
}
```

but I have no idea how I measure the time in seconds.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measure execution time in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903222/measure-execution-time-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) and [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) (Be careful to use DateTime.UtcNow to avoid issues with daylight saving boundaries)

e.g.

```
var start = DateTime.UtcNow;
...
var end = DateTime.UtcNow;
var elapsed = end.Subtract(start); //elapsed is a TimeSpan
var elapsedSeconds = elsapsed.Seconds;
```

This can also be done with a [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) (which is more accurate and doesn't suffer from problems with daylight saving boundaries)

```
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
...
stopwatch.Stop();
var elapsedSeconds = stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds; //stopwatch.Elapsed is a TimeSpan
```

Comment: What type is elapsedSeconds? If not int, how do I make it an int?

Comment: Yes, it's an int.

Answer (score 0):

In this solution you will see how to get the time between the method call
[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
class Program
{
  static Stopwatch _stopWatch = new Stopwatch(); // stopwatch
  static long  _lastTime; // time in milliseconds


  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     /* _lastTime will be 0 when first call ElapsedTime(). */
     ElapsedTime();

     /* Hold the current thread for 1000 milliseconds */ 
     Thread.Sleep(1000); 

     /* _lastTime will be 1000  when second call ElapsedTime(). */
     ElapsedTime(); 
     Thread.Sleep(2000);

     /* _lastTime will be 3000 when third call ElapsedTime(). */
     ElapsedTime();

     /* Thread.Sleep() is to simulate time between the calls of the method */ 
     /* _lastTime is in milliseconds*/
   }


   public static void ElapsedTime()
   {
     // check if stopwatch already started once
     if (_stopWatch .IsRunning) 
     {
         /* get the totlal elapsed milliseconds */
         _lastTime += _stopWatch .ElapsedMilliseconds;
         /* Restart stopwatch */
         _stopWatch .Restart();
      }
      else
      {
        _stopWatch .Start();
      }

     Console.WriteLine(_lastTime);
   }
}
```